# AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'find' (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

The scrapy error I get is:

```
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 82, in urljoin
    return urljoin(get_base_url(self), url)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 261, in urljoin
    urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 143, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 182, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'Selector' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Scrapy traced the call back to this line in my spider:

```
for url in links:
    link_url = response.urljoin(url)
```

This line is in a generic parse() method. I have ran the exact same syntax many times before and never encountered an error, and wading through the documentation and source code for urllib did not yield anything.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact url looking like, which causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

## Factors that triggers your error

- The environment you are using **python27**
- You had sent a **scrapy.selector** object to **urljoin**

## How to re-trigger the error

- Activate anaconda python **2.7** environment

  - Open a scrapy shell with target url `www.bing.com`

    ```
    scrapy shell www.bing.com
    ```
  - Import `Selector` from `scrapy.selector` using:

    ```
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    ```
  - Create a `Selector` object from your response

    ```
    selector_obj = Selector(response=response)
    ```
  - Use `response.urljoin` to join the `Selector` object

    ```
    response.urljoin(selector_obj)
    ```
  - The same error occurs
    [image]

### How to fix your error

- Check the `url` variable using `type()` or other technique, make sure you had extract the **string** you desired properly

  ```
  for url in links:
      link_url = response.urljoin(url)
  ```
- Use python **3.x** instead of python *2.7*, when scrapy runs with python **3.x**, the error message will be much clear and easy to understand. (Here is the same error in python36 environment)

[image]

Comment: This solves it - thank you so much for all of your help! I sincerely appreciate it : )